# I can retrieve entities but I can't persist WebSphere 7 JPA

Tags: jpa, websphere, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am dealing with an application developed in NetBeans. It uses a single entity and can either retrieve from DB or persist new entities. It uses JPA 2.0 w/ EclipseLink. When deployed in bundled Glassfish, it works correctly. However, when deploying into WAS 7.0.0.9 (already includes the JPA 2.0 patch), I can retrieve entities, but I can't persist them.

My code to persist, within a Stateless EJB 3.0 is:

```
public void create(MyEntity entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

I've set the logging property to FINEST, so I can get more detail,

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
```

but all I get in the log is:

```
[EL Finer]: 2011-07-11 17:02:59.813--UnitOfWork(1634296169)--Thread(Thread[WebContainer : 9,5,main])--initialize identitymaps
[EL Finer]: 2011-07-11 17:02:59.815--ServerSession(833630640)--Thread(Thread[WebContainer : 9,5,main])--client acquired
[EL Finest]: 2011-07-11 17:02:59.815--UnitOfWork(137562163)--Thread(Thread[WebContainer : 9,5,main])--PERSIST operation called on: PU_TEST.
[EL Finer]: 2011-07-11 17:02:59.816--UnitOfWork(137562163)--Thread(Thread[WebContainer : 9,5,main])--initialize identitymaps
```

The server logs show no info about this either. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**
This is the working persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="fonacotCap" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/fonacotCap</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebSphere_7"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Informix"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>** 
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="/opt/apps/libs/persistence.log"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

Comment: See updated persistence.xml file. That's the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured eclipselink as your persistence provider? By default WAS uses its own persistence provider (which wraps OpenJPA).

[Configuring WAS Persistence Provider](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html)

Comment: Thanks Terrell. I have actually configured that in the persistence.xml file. I just added the persistence.xml to the initial question.
Additionally, I've added the EclipseLink jar to the class path of the app. Not sure if I need anything else.

Comment: I found a solution. I needed to modify the persistence.xml. I edited the original question with an update reflecting extra lines.

Comment: Please do not only post link-only answers. If the link contains the answer, put the relevant part of the answer in your answer on StackOverflow. If the content behind the link changes, or the content is removed, your answer does not answer this question anymore.